# Mathematica: Using ParametricNDSolve and NMinimize to fit data set

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, differential-equations

I have a system of 3 coupled ODEs that depend on 2 variables, $a$ and $\epsilon$. I used `ParametricNDSolve` to obtain the parametric solutions. I now want to use `FindFit` or `NMinimize` to fit the parameters to two sets of data of the form `avgx={{t1,x1}, {t2,x2}, ...}` and `avgy={{t1,y1}, {t2,y2}, ...}`. ParametricNDSolve gives the three functions, `bx[t],by[t],bz[t]`, but I only want to fit `bx[t]`  and `by[t]` to the two data sets.

However, I run into the error message "the function value is not a number at...". I previously asked a similar question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/nminimize-parametricndsolve-function-value-is-not-a-number?noredirect=1#comment710783_285467. I manage to fit one parametric function to one data set (i.e. I fit `bx[t]` to `avgx` using FindFit but the fit is not good when comparing `by[t]` to `avgy`; actually the fit is not very good for `bx[t]` either, even though I passed `NMinimize` as the `Method` for `FindFit`.

I tried passing both `_Real` and `_?NumericQ` and neither works.

The code is pasted below

```
Rx0 = 5.438492505*10^(-6);
Ry0=1.810129219*10^(-6);
Rz0 =1.800*10^(-6);
Nmol=500;

avgdatax={{0,10^(-6)*5.438492505},{0.005,10^(-6)*6.5160082},{0.01,10^(-6)*9.095890911},{0.015,10^(-6)*12.61828077},{0.02,10^(-6)*16.33799269}};
avgdatay={{0,10^(-6)*1.810129219},{0.005,10^(-6)*5.965897406},{0.01,10^(-6)*9.938865494},{0.015,10^(-6)*14.40682942},{0.02,10^(-6)*18.46942262}};

avgdata={{0,10^(-6)*5.438492505,10^(-6)*1.810129219},{0.005,10^(-6)*6.5160082,10^(-6)*5.965897406},{0.01,10^(-6)*9.095890911,10^(-6)*9.938865494},{0.015,10^(-6)*12.61828077,10^(-6)*14.40682942},{0.02,10^(-6)*16.33799269,10^(-6)*18.46942262}};

au = 1.66054*10^(-27);
m = 155.895*au;
a0=5.29177210903*10^(-11);
\[HBar]=1.054571817*10^(-34);
l=(15*(\[HBar])^2*Nmol)/(m^2);

kx0=Rx0/Rz0;
ky0=Ry0/Rz0;

Rx[t_]:=bx[t]*Rx0;
Ry[t_]:=by[t]*Ry0;
Rz[t_]:=bz[t]*Rz0;

kyz[t_]:=Ry[t]/Rz[t];
kxz[t_]:=Rx[t]/Rz[t];

\[Omega]bar12a[t_]:=l/((Rx[t])^2*(Rx[t]*Ry[t]*Rz[t]));
\[Omega]bar22a[t_]:=l/((Ry[t])^2*(Rx[t]*Ry[t]*Rz[t]));
\[Omega]bar32a[t_]:=l/((Rz[t])^2*(Rx[t]*Ry[t]*Rz[t]));

\[Phi][kyz_]=ArcSin[Sqrt[1-(kyz)^2]];
sin\[Alpha]2[kxz_,kyz_]:=(1-(kxz)^2)/(1-(kyz)^2);

f[x_,y_]=1+3*x*y*(EllipticE[ArcSin[Sqrt[1-x^2]],(1-y^2)/(1-x^2)]-EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1-x^2]],(1-y^2)/(1-x^2)])/((1-y^2)*Sqrt[1-x^2]);

system = {bx''[t]==(\[Omega]bar12a[t]*(a*a0))/((bx[t])^2*by[t]*bz[t])*(1-(\[Epsilon]*f[(by[t]/bz[t])*ky0,(bx[t]/bz[t])*kx0])-(\[Epsilon]*bx[t]*D[f[(by[t]/bz[t])*ky0,(bx[t]/bz[t])*kx0],bx[t]])),
by''[t]==(\[Omega]bar22a[t]*(a*a0))/(bx[t]*(by[t])^2*bz[t])*(1-(\[Epsilon]*f[(by[t]/bz[t])*ky0,(bx[t]/bz[t])*kx0])-(\[Epsilon]*by[t]*D[f[(by[t]/bz[t])*ky0,(bx[t]/bz[t])*kx0],by[t]])),
bz''[t]==(\[Omega]bar32a[t]*(a*a0))/(bx[t]*by[t]*(bz[t])^2)*(1-(\[Epsilon]*f[(by[t]/bz[t])*ky0,(bx[t]/bz[t])*kx0])-(\[Epsilon]*bz[t]*D[f[(by[t]/bz[t])*ky0,(bx[t]/bz[t])*kx0],bz[t]])), bx[0]==1,by[0]==1,bz[0]==1,bx'[0]==0,by'[0]==0,bz'[0]==0};

data = Table[10^(-6)*rawdataRx1[[i]][[2]],{i,1,5}];
solx= ParametricNDSolve[system,{bx},{t,0,0.03},{a,\[Epsilon]}];
soly=ParametricNDSolve[system,{by},{t,0,0.03},{a,\[Epsilon]}];
solz=ParametricNDSolve[system,{bz},{t,0,0.03},{a,\[Epsilon]}];

b1=bx/.solx;
b2=by/.soly;
b3=bz/.solz;

datax=Table[avgdata[[i]][[2]],{i,1,5}]
datay=Table[avgdata[[i]][[3]],{i,1,5}]

objfnx[a_Real, \[Epsilon]_Real] := 
 Norm[(( Rx0* solx[t][a, \[Epsilon]] /.  t -> #  ) & /@ 
     Table[i, {i, 0, 0.02,0.005}]) - datax]
objfny[a_Real, \[Epsilon]_Real] := 
 Norm[(( Ry0* soly[t][a, \[Epsilon]] /.  t -> #  ) & /@ 
     Table[i, {i, 0, 0.02,0.005}]) - datay]
 
NMinimize[{objfnx[a, \[Epsilon]]+objfny[a,\[Epsilon]], a > 0, \[Epsilon] > 0}, {a, \[Epsilon]}]
```

I'm also not sure if summing the two norms will fit the parameters appropriately.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.